# Sorting a 2d array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Im having a little of a hard time figuring out the specifics of a line of code that sorts a 2d array of integers.

The array that is being sorted is an array that has arrays inside that only have two numbers, I am trying to figure out if `(a, b)` refers to two separate 2d  arrays and if `(a[0] , b[0])` refers to the numbers within the 2d arrays?

```java
Arrays.sort(sortedIntervals, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *key extractor* and *comparator chaining*:

```java
int[][] arr2d = {{1, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 3}};

// sorting the rows of a 2d array first by
// the first column, then by the second column
Arrays.sort(arr2d, Comparator
        .<int[]>comparingInt(row -> row[0])
        .thenComparingInt(row -> row[1]));

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr2d));
// [[0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Arrays.sort(sortedIntervals, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a[0] , b[0]));

As you can [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) there is only one method compare: `compare(int,int)`. So `a[0]` must be a int (or a java.lang.Integer, respecievly).

Since there is only one method accepting a lambda as second parameter it must be [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)). And it's javadoc sais `a` and `b` are direct elements of the array `sortedIntervals` and `a` and `b` must be an array of ints.

So there is no other option than `sortedIntervals` is a 2dim array of integers. Since we can access a[0] and b[0] we can expect that all direct elements of `sortedIntervals` have in their first position can be cast to `int`.

Also we can predict that

```
int[][] sortedIntervals ={{},{}}; 
int[][] sortedIntervals ={{6},{}}; 
int[][] sortedIntervals ={{},{6}};
```

will always throw a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` inside the lambda because the index `0` does not exists in at least one of the elements.