# Sorting a 2d matrix first by X and then by Y

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array

```java
int[][] points = new int[n][2];
..
//sort by x values and then y if x's are the same
Arrays.sort(points, (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0] == 0 ? a[1] - b[1] : a[0] - b[0]);
```

Is this an optimal solution? I just tested it in my IDE with some random numbers and it seems work.

Answer (score 1):

Optimal compared to what other solution?  You are sorting a two dimensional array and supplying a Comparator to govern the sort.  `Arrays.sort` implements an efficient, stable sorting algorithm.  I would use it but I would specify the comparator as follows:

```
Arrays.sort(points, Comparator.comparingInt((int[] a) -> a[0])
            .thenComparingInt(a -> a[1]));
```

Subtracting elements to adhere to the requirements of the Comparator is not a good practice and can result in improperly sorted data structures when the values are near `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I didnt know comparingInt was something that existed. Could we also use Integer.compareTo to avoid overflows?

Comment: Integer compareTo compares two Integer Objects like `obj1.compareTo(obj2)` which wouldn;t work for primitives.  But you can do `Integer.compare(a,b)` where a and b are ints.  In fact, that's what `Comparator.comparingInt` uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *comparator chaining* as follows:

```java
int[][] points;
// sorting the rows of a 2d array first by the
// first column and then by the second column
Arrays.sort(points, Comparator
        .<int[], Integer>comparing(arr -> arr[0])
        .thenComparing(arr -> arr[1]));
```

---

<sup>See also: [Sorting a 2d array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67181501/15933560)</sup>